# Incompatibility between graph NLP and leaflet

Tags: r, shiny, nlp, r-leaflet, incompatibility

I have a shiny R application in which I have a leaflet card and also an NLP object from LDAvis. There seems to be an incompatibility between the LDAvis graph object and leaflet, as the geometries on the map are not displayed.

To display the LDAvis graph, execute the commented code and generate the objects (json, js, ...) in the line `lda_model$plot(...)` and then load the generated json file into the `readlines` function

```
library(shiny)
library(LDAvis)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leaflet::leafletOutput("mymap"),
  tags$br(),
  tags$br(),
  
  LDAvis::visOutput('ldavis_plot')
)





server <- function(input, output) {
  

  output$mymap <- leaflet::renderLeaflet({
    leaflet::leaflet() %>% leaflet::addTiles() %>%
      leaflet::addRectangles(
        lng1=-118.456554, lat1=34.078039,
        lng2=-118.436383, lat2=34.062717,
        fillColor = "transparent"
      )
  })
  
  
  
  
  output$ldavis_plot <- LDAvis::renderVis({
    # tokens = tolower(movie_review$review[1:1000])
    # tokens = word_tokenizer(tokens)
    # it = itoken(tokens, ids = movie_review$id[1:1000], progressbar = FALSE)
    # v = create_vocabulary(it)
    # v = prune_vocabulary(v, term_count_min = 10, doc_proportion_max = 0.2)
    # 
    # vectorizer = vocab_vectorizer(v)
    # dtm = create_dtm(it, vectorizer, type = "dgTMatrix")
    # 
    # lda_model = text2vec::LDA$new(n_topics = 5, doc_topic_prior = 0.1, topic_word_prior = 0.01)
    # doc_topic_distr = 
    #   lda_model$fit_transform(x = dtm, n_iter = 100, 
    #                           convergence_tol = 0.001, n_check_convergence = 25, 
    #                           progressbar = FALSE)
    # 
    # lda_model$plot(out.dir = "PATH_TO", open.browser = FALSE)
    
    
    readLines("PATH_TO/lda.json")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get around this incompatibility?

Comment: You need to share some data, `dput()` so we can see it or play with it ourselves

Comment: I can't put in the data because the ```plot``` function produces 4-5 files. Even without the LDAvis object and with the definition in the ui and in the server the geometry on the leaflet doesn't work

Comment: Not seeing the original data structure, it is almost impossible to be useful.